# How to implement alternative login for asp.net forms authentication?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-authentication

I have an existing website using forms authentication with Sql provider. Now i am trying to integrate with another website and use their authentication mechanism. I am already able to validate a user  and trying to silently login the user into my application. Here is the code for "silent" login:

```
if (user != null) // logged in!
{
    IPrincipal principal = new MyPrincipal(user);
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.ScreenName, true);

    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

and it works with the exception that Forms Authentication overrides the `HttpContext.Current.User` by the time i make it "default.aspx". Is there a way to bypass forms role and membership providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a custom principal, the custom principal must be established on every request to the web server; it's not persisted.  Adding code to reload it in global.asax would resolve it.  Others have created an HTTP module to do this too.

HTH.

Comment: nope, copied the code (except redirect) into Application_AuthenticateRequest, same thing, by the time i hit Default.aspx the user is overwritten

Comment: actually it works if disable roleManage, can i make it work with the role manager? can i add a second rolemanager somehow?

Comment: I'll mark this as answer. multiple roles is a different question i guess. Thanks!!!

Comment: RoleManager always pulls from the primary provider; you can make a custom role provider to bridge the gap.